# Intermittent access to HTTPS sites through iptables MASQUERADING

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, https, timeout, masquerade

The problem: everything is fine on the network, except every once in a while, all https times out for all the hosts on the network. After a few minutes it goes back to being near-instant for several hours.

The details:

I'm running an Ubuntu Server 12.04 with 2 NICS:

- NIC 1 is WAN, dhcp from cable modem
- NIC 2 is LAN, 192.168.0.1 connected to a router's WAN port 192.168.0.2
- All iptables chains have accept policies until I get things working
- All traffic from 192.168.0.0/16 is masqueraded from to the WAN port
- All forwarding from 192.168.0.0/16 is accepted
- All forwarding to 192.168.0.0/16 is accepted if established or related
- Same three rules above for 10.0.0.0/16 because I've been testing out other configurations

The router: Asus rt-n56u

- Everything on the LAN is DHCP within 10.0.0.0/24 (2.4ghz,5ghz and LAN ports)
- NAT from the 10.0.0.1 Gateway out to 192.168.0.1 through the WAN port
- No static routing configured)
- The built-in firewall is disabled for now

Below you'll find my /etc/network/interfaces,iptables settings and ifconfig. Please let me know if any other information would be helpful.

```
###############################################################
/etc/network/interfaces:

#connects to the cable modem
auto WAN
iface WAN inet dhcp

#connects to the LAN router
auto LAN
iface LAN inet static
address 192.168.0.1
network 192.168.0.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255

#loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


###############################################################
iptables rules:

#I've set all the chains to accept. Once I get everything working, I'll implement a whitelist.

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

#turn on NAT for /16 subnet by mangling with the MASQUERADE module
iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/16 -o WAN -j MASQUERADE
iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/16 -o WAN -j MASQUERADE

#allow all traffic from the /16 subnet to WAN
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/16 -o WAN -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/16 -i LAN -o WAN -j ACCEPT

#allow traffic from the WAN to the /16 subnet if a connection was established b$
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.0.0/16 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -i WAN -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.0/16 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -i WAN -j ACCEPT

#drop packets that attempt to spoof source LAN IPs
iptables -A INPUT -i WAN -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i WAN -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j DROP

###############################################################
ifconfig:

LAN   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:4d:a1:5d:42
inet addr:192.168.0.1  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::222:4dff:fea1:5d42/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:53737 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:136493 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:8626679 (8.6 MB)  TX bytes:178113059 (178.1 MB)
Interrupt:17 Memory:d0020000-d0040000

WAN   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:4d:a1:5d:3e
inet addr:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Bcast:255.255.255.255  Mask:255.255.255.224
(external IP sensored)
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:576  Metric:1
RX packets:142317 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:54748 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:178555294 (178.5 MB)  TX bytes:8369828 (8.3 MB)
Interrupt:16 Memory:d0120000-d0140000

lo   Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
RX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:1474 (1.4 KB)  TX bytes:1474 (1.4 KB)
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you experience the same problems for https connections originating *on* your gateway server?  Or just for systems behind the Asus router?  Also, is there any particular reason that you're double-masquerading (systems behind the router appear to map from 10.0.0.0/24 to 192.168.0.0/24, which in turn maps to your external ip address)?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

DHCP on WAN was setting the MTU to 576 (as seen in ifconfig).

Solution:

-Simply removed interface-mtu from the request list in /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf (to stop my server from getting the bad value of 576 from my ISP).

-Added "mtu 1500" under "iface WAN inet dhcp" in /etc/network/interfaces

Reboot.

Everything is tip-top now.

Comment: You're a genius.